# Making Puppeteer goto different links at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I need to make my api that scrapes a list of urls faster. Right now I go to each page one at a time and add the data to an array. I need to open multiple links at once and add the data I get from it into the same array.

This is my code:

```
var videos = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < profile.videoLinks.length; i++){
            await page.goto(profile.videoLinks[i].video, {
                // waitUntil: 'load'
            });
            await page.waitForSelector('.music-info')
            var vidInfo = await page.evaluate(() => {
                const vidTitle = document.querySelector('.video-meta-title').innerText;
                const musicInfo = document.querySelector('.music-info').innerText;
                const musicLink = document.querySelector('.music-info a').href;
                const likes = document.querySelector('.like-text').innerText;
                const comments = document.querySelector('.comment-text').innerText;

                return {
                    vidTitle,
                    musicInfo,
                    musicLink,
                    likes,
                    comments
                }
            })
            videos.push(vidInfo);
```

Right now, my array of links is in `profile.videoLinks[ ].video`. Should I split the array in half then use evaluate function on each array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I optimize your code by using [BrowserContext](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v3.3.0&show=api-class-browsercontext). and scraping all links in parallel using Promise.all().

Run it and tell me if everything is good.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const profile = {
  videoLinks: [{ video: "https://example.com/video.mp4" }],
};

const doMyBusiness = async (browser, video) => {
  const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();

  await page.goto(video, {
    // waitUntil: 'load'
  });

  await page.waitForSelector(".music-info");

  const vidInfo = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const vidTitle = document.querySelector(".video-meta-title").innerText;
    const musicInfo = document.querySelector(".music-info").innerText;
    const musicLink = document.querySelector(".music-info a").href;
    const likes = document.querySelector(".like-text").innerText;
    const comments = document.querySelector(".comment-text").innerText;

    return {
      vidTitle,
      musicInfo,
      musicLink,
      likes,
      comments,
    };
  });

  await context.close();

  return vidInfo;
};

const main = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

  const videos = await Promise.all(
    profile.videoLinks.map((video) => doMyBusiness(browser, video))
  );

  console.log(videos);

  await browser.close();
};
```

Edited my code to can handle a lot of videos by work with small chunks.

NOTE: I'm using puppeteer to **scraping** title of list of links. you should edit page.waitForSelector() & page.evaluate() to apply your business.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const profile = {
  videoLinks: [
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://linkedin.com' },
    { video: 'https://stackoverflow.com' },
    { video: 'https://facebook.com' },
    { video: 'https://apple.com' },
    { video: 'https://leetcode.com' },
    { video: 'https://codewars.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
    { video: 'https://google.com' },
  ],
};

const doMyBusiness = async (browser, video) => {
  const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();

  await page.goto(video, {
    // waitUntil: 'load'
  });

  await page.waitForSelector('title');

  const vidInfo = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const vidTitle = document.querySelector('title').innerText;

    return {
      vidTitle,
    };
  });

  await context.close();

  return vidInfo;
};

const main = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const videos = [];
  const chunkLength = 10;

  for (let i = 0, len = profile.videoLinks.length; i < len; i += chunkLength) {
    const chunkOfLinks = profile.videoLinks.slice(i, i + chunkLength);

    const chunkOfVideos = await Promise.all(
      chunkOfLinks.map(videoLink =>
        doMyBusiness(browser, videoLink.video).catch(err => err),
      ),
    );

    videos.push(...chunkOfVideos);
  }

  console.log({ videos });

  await browser.close();
};

main();
```

Comment: Ive tried this and lets say I have 30 urls to scrape, I get navigation error time limit exceeded. It still takes too long.

Comment: Hello Chris, I edited my code to fix your issue. I test it in my local machine and work successfully with a lot of links (1000 link).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`puppeteer-cluster`](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster) to run the tasks in parallel (I'm the author of that library). You can specify how many pages (or browsers) you want to use in parallel. The library then takes care of that to run your task(s).

**Code Sample**

```js
const { Cluster } = require('puppeteer-cluster');

const videos = [];

(async () => {
    // Setup a cluster with 4 browsers in parallel
    const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
        concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_BROWSER,
        maxConcurrency: 4,
    });

    // Define your task to be executed
    await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: url }) => {
        await page.goto(url);
        await page.waitForSelector('.music-info');

        var vidInfo = await page.evaluate(/* ... */);
        videos.push(vidInfo);
    });

    // Queue your URLs
    for(var i = 0; i < profile.videoLinks.length; i++){
        cluster.queue(profile.videoLinks[i].video);
    }

    // Wait for the cluster to finish and close it
    await cluster.idle();
    await cluster.close();
})();
```